# HTML5 video path confusion

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, video, razor, video.js

I have been playing with Video.js and have run into a problem with the example provided.

When specifying an MP4 (h264) video, using the html5 video element, there is some confusion.

When I use (absolute):

```
<source src="C:\<filsystempath>\Media\oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

The video is displayed, no problem. But when I use:

```
<source src="@Url.Content("~/Media/oceans-clip.mp4")" type='video/mp4' />
```

The video is not displayed. I would conclude that the using a relative path is the problem but when using an ogv video like so:

```
<source src="@Url.Content("~/Media/oceans-clip.ogv")" type='video/ogg' />
```

It works fine.

One more annoyance - When the video is used for flash fallback, it works.

I am using ASP.MVC and video.js. I am using localhost to debug.

Full video tag -

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
   controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
   poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
   data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="@Url.Content("~/Media/oceans-clip.ogv")" type='video/ogg' /> -- Works
<source src="C:\<filesystempath>\oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' /> -- Works
<source src="@Url.Content("~/Media/oceans-clip.mp4")" type='video/mp4' /> -- Doesn't work
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>
```

The question is: Why will the video play with an absolute path but not a relative one?

Answer (score 2):

Because this `<source src="@Url.Content("~/Media/oceans-clip.mp4")" type='video/mp4' />` renderes something like:

```
<source src="localhost:8080/Media/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

And in first case, you are reading file from drive:

```
<source src="C:\<filsystempath>\Media\oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
```

Comment: I would conclude that the using a relative path is the problem but when using an ogv video like so:

<source src="@Url.Content("~/Media/oceans-clip.ogv")" type='video/ogg' />
It works fine.

Comment: @user2008963 `<source src="C:\<filsystempath>\Media\oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />` this reads file from client computer! and this reads from server: `<source src="localhost:8080/Media/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple. Use IIS express. Not sure how or why this works but I think it has something to do with the applicationhost.config file in C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config. Maybe MP4s need mime types specified to work. Like I said, not sure. Hope this helps someone else.

Also, credit to karaxuna for making me think.